# anyway to write dlls in linux?

Tags: linux, dll

Is there anyway to write dlls in linux? 
Do I have to install windows to write dlls in linux? Right now one of my courses requires me to write a dll for this.

Comment: A DLL is a Windows-specific library while Linux uses Shared Objects instead. Although with Wine, you could use Windows DLLs when you're writing Windows application that also run under Linux. Are you creating Windows applications for Wine/Linux?

Comment: *"one of my courses are pretty retarded and requires me to write a dll"* It is worth considering that when your course work requires you to do something that looks stupid there is a chance (but no guarantee) that the teacher know something you don't.

Comment: "Right now one of my courses are pretty retarded"  I love when people call others (or things) stupid by using incorrect grammar and words like "retarded".

Answer (score 9):

You should take a look into 'shared libraries'
http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Answer (score 1):

Lots of folks are getting near the right answer but not providing it: gcc can generate win32 PE/COFF files without problem, and of course can always build as a cross compiler on any platform it can target.  The binutils port targets windows .exe and .dll files natively, and there's a "dlltool" utility for handling the edge cases where Unix and Windows linkage metaphors are different.

Additionally, the "mingw32" project provides a set of link libraries and header files for building C applications against the win32 API.  These likewise install just fine on any Unix.

Here's a site I turned up after a quick google with [instructions for building the toolchain](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW).

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Building any kind of executable intended for OS "A" while using OS "B" is a process commonly known as **cross-compilation**. In this partciluar case, you would need a cross-compiler running on Linux, but targetting Windows. I don't know any vendor selling such a product.

Comment: Don't be silly.  GCC/mingw has been a magnificent win32 cross compiler for years now.  It works fine, it builds out of the box on every platform supported by gcc, and frankly the toolchain integration is better than Microsoft's products for a lot of purposes.  It's not an "easy" solution (I think the previous answer about shared libraries might be a better fit), but it certainly isn't an impossibility.